# When I say multi+something, what's between them?

Tags: grammar

For example, if I want to talk about programming with multiple files instead of one big one, I would say multi file programming. Or is it multifile without a space? Or is it multi-file with a hyphen? How do I handle multi+something?

Comment: I think this is a question of style rather than grammar. I would use a hyphen. (And speaking as a programmer, I don't know what you mean by "multi-file programming". If you're talking about multiple source code and resource files for a single application, that's the norm for many languages, it's not really something that needs to be pointed out.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Multi-file programming is using several source code files for a project, rather than one.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes. I would use a hyphen. No idea about the files.

Comment: Unless it has become a common term, like "multiprocessing" or "multitasking", I think it's normal to use a hyphen.